# asp.net core 3.1 signalr core error "firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://domain.com"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-3.1, signalr-hub

i have an asp.netcore 3.1 web application that using signalr core.

i copied the app in 2 identical servers. in server #1 everything works fine in fireFox and chrome.

but server #2 app i get this error just in firefox

> firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://domain.com
>
> Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: There was an error
> with the transport.

and after 20 seconds the connection will establish successfully in SSE.

i know that its a 'by design' error, and it seems its a common error in FF when using Sockets. but i did not found any Working Solution.

the question is why im getting this error while the server #1 is working perfectly fine? and how can i resolve this?

Comment: Please check if  you enabled support for the WebSocket Protocol on server #2.

Comment: i double checked and it is enabled. as i said, the app connects with WS in chrome perfectly fine.